# How to change console font size in console in ATOM abbrev@1.0.7

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I am using ATOM for all my scripting. There is a package named "Script" where you can run your script from within ATOM by pressing Shift+Ctrl+Space. The command opens a console box at the bottom and shows you the script output. Does anyone know how to change the fontsize[image]

Answer (score 22):

You can edit *your stylesheet*:
Edit -> Preferences -> Themes
And in *your stylesheet* write:

```
.script-view .line {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Then save it and reboot Atom

Answer (score 0):

Adding .atom-runner pre { font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; } into atom-runner.less may make it better

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Novik answer's did not work for me. Instead, I watch this video on youtube. It's saying you have to change the font size in the editor section.

I am not going to take credit for it. here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfgbYB1AIT4).