# How to Increase Terminal Font Size in atom

Tags: atom-editor, font-size

The terminal font size is too small in atom.

I am unable to increase it. However the editor font size can be increased easily.

[image: Showing problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change console font size in console in ATOM abbrev@1.0.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849774/how-to-change-console-font-size-in-console-in-atom-abbrev1-0-7)

Comment: Are you using platformia-ide-terminal to get an in-app terminal? If not how do you get a terminal in atom?

Comment: i can maybe help you with this information.